# Django CORS Headers not Working as Suggested in Docs

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, cors, django-cors-headers

The DOCS for Django Cors Headers, https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/ ,
clearly states that `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`:

> Previously this setting
> was called `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`, which still works as an alias, with
> the new name taking precedence.

From the code if I use `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` my requests go through, but if I use `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`, while commenting out `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`, my requests are blocked. In my options request I am not getting any response and the subsequent POST request is blocked.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #APPS
    ....

    #ADDL FRAMEWORKS
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'django_extensions',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    'http://localhost:3000'
]

# CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
#     'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
#     'http://localhost:3000',
# ]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]
```

Comment: which version of `django-cors-headers` do you use?

Comment: Thanks a lot, should have been the first place I should have checked. I am on version **3.4.0** and they updated the name in **3.5.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a ***VERSION*** mistake. The `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` was changed to `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN` in version `3.5.0`, while it would seem that i am running an older version.